# Should Gherkin 'Then' statements refer to 'I'

Tags: testing, automation, cucumber, bdd, gherkin

I've been using Gherkin (with Cucumber) for many years now.  I noticed early on that Cucumber.io homepage examples refer to 'I' in the given and when statements, but not in the then statements.

I always assumed this was because given and when statements are subjective actions by a user, where as then statements should be objective measures about the state of the application under test.

However, I noticed in the official Cucumber book, their examples refer to 'I' all the way through the steps (including when using then statements).

Anyone know which method is correct?

Comment: Quick answer from me: I prefer nouns over pronouns. There's less confusion by readers.

Comment: @charlie, could you get me the link of that document?

Comment: Hey @charlie-s, its now been eight years since you asked this question. Did any of the answers help :D

Answer (score 2):

There is not a definitive rule as to whether "Then" statements should include "I". As @ekostadinov says, it depends on the Actors which are taking part in the test scenario.

For instance in a messaging scenario:

```
Given Alice is on a messaging page
When Alice posts a message to Bob
Then Bob should receive the message
```

In such a scenario it would make no sense to use "I" in the "Then". However if you had a slightly different scenario:

```
Given I am on the messaging page
When I post a message to Bob
Then I should receive confirmation that Bob received the message
```

Then using "I" does make sense.

Hence it depends on how you write your tests. To conclude, I prefer to use personas (i.e. particular types of users in your system) throughout my tests e.g. Alice, Bob etc. This generally removes any possible ambiguity with the use of "I".

Answer (score 1):

In my experience regarding the BDD and Gherkinri, we've always considered that the User story has two actors: User and System. Not all actors are end users. For example, a role could be another system or someone who wants certain functionality in order to buy your product but will never actually use the product. It may be useful to create aggregate roles (such as consumer) and specialized roles (such as browser or frequent shopper). So having *I* in the *Then* steps is actually expected result from end-user's perspective. Example:

```
Then I should see that cash amount 'storedTotalAmount' and cash amount 'currentAmount' are equal 'true'
```

Comment: Glad to help @Aravin.